# Binding events between BackboneJS and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

I had an app that I had already built using Backbone and now have decided to use Angular for its "Controller" Module.

I'm trying to find a way to bind angulars ng-repeat events to the collections reset event but can't seem to have an idea what to do.

I am not verse in AngularJS but do know my way around the Backbone framework.

Can someone enlighten me on this scenario?